# how to detect if a activity is on top

Tags: android, android-activity

In the app having background service running, periodical it will trigger some event that app needs to show an activity.

The issue is if that activity is already on top how to not open another one.

The following snippet whenever the event is triggered, the showAlertActivity() will try to open the activity (it is not just a alert).

Any way to check if there is one has been opened? Thanks!

```
public void showAlertActivity(String title, String msg……) {

    // this does not work, throws a exception 
    //“ava.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from pid=24139, uid=10048 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS”
    ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService( Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );

    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo info: taskList) {


        Log.d(“+++ info.numActivities:" + info.numActivities +", info.topActivity.getClassName():"+info.topActivity.getClassName()+", info.baseActivity:"+info.baseActivity.getClassName());


    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TheAlertActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.putExtra(Constants.LAYOUT_RESOURCE_ID, R.layout.alert_form);
    dialogIntent.putExtra(Constants.TILTLE, title);
    dialogIntent.putExtra(Constants.TEXT, msg);
    ……
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Use flag reorder to front

Comment: Thanks Tim! tried adding android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest, when first time the function called, saw activity onCreated() and newIntent() get called then whole app disappear. When next time the function triggered to be called the app is brought back with the activity on top. why the first time lunch causes the app goes away?

Comment: I said reorder to front though, not single task :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add something along the lines of this to your Activity you want to check and `isOpen` will tell you if it is currently on top.

```
public static boolean isOpen = false;
private static int countOpen = 0;

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    countOpen++;
    isOpen = countOpen > 0;
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    countOpen--;
    isOpen = countOpen > 0;
}
```

The count is added to secure the boolean being correct even if you open the activity for some reason in front of itself and the system sometimes calling the new activities `onStart()` before the old activities `onStop()`.

Comment: thanks Jj, but not a good solution, have to say. This way it will start more than one activity. Really want to prevent the second one from start